CheckBox not updating status when it is checked again
In my adapter class I have RecylerView viewHolder in which i am using checkbox to get the response
of user
public class SecondViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   private CheckBox optionA, optionB,optionC,optionD;
         public SecondViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
   optionA = itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionA);
        optionB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionB);
        optionC = itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionC);
        optionD = itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionD);
   }  
   private void bindData(final  int pos) {
        optionA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        optionB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        optionC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        optionD.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        optionA.setChecked(false);
        optionB.setChecked(false);
        optionC.setChecked(false);
        optionD.setChecked(false);
  int selectedAns = g_question.get(pos).getSelectedAns();
        Log.d("SecondViewHolder", "SelectedAns for pos " + pos + ": " + selectedAns);

        setCheckBoxListeners(pos);
 private void setCheckBoxListeners(final int pos) {
        optionA.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> selectOption(pos));
        optionB.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> selectOption(pos));
        optionC.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> selectOption(pos));
        optionD.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> selectOption(pos));
    }

    private void selectOption(int pos) {
        int status = 0;
        if (optionA.isChecked()) status += 1;
        if (optionB.isChecked()) status += 2;
        if (optionC.isChecked()) status += 4;
        if (optionD.isChecked()) status += 8;

        g_question.get(pos).setSelectedAns(status);
        changeStatus(pos, status);


    }

    private void changeStatus(int id, int status) {
        if (g_question.get(id).getStatus() != Review) {
            g_question.get(id).setStatus(status);
        }
    }

when user click on the checkbox again then checkbox is getting unselected but the status is not restoring previous value
I have try to  update the checkbox
         updateCheckBoxStates(selectedAns);
    private void updateCheckBoxStates(int selectedAns) {
    optionA.setChecked((selectedAns & 1) != 0);
    optionB.setChecked((selectedAns & 2) != 0);
    optionC.setChecked((selectedAns & 4) != 0);
    optionD.setChecked((selectedAns & 8) != 0);
} 

but this is updating all the checkbox is selected by default
